# How to fix Y axis is off by 30 mm?

Tags: klipper, skr-mini-e3, ender3

I have Ender 3 with Klipper.

In my config:

```
[stepper_y]
step_pin: PB10
dir_pin: !PB2
enable_pin: !PB11
microsteps: 16
rotation_distance: 40
endstop_pin: ^PC1
position_min: -30
position_endstop: -30
position_max: 200
homing_speed: 50
```

With this, when I issue `G1 X0 Y0` the printhead is actually at 0,0 above left bottom corner.

But then it may not move farther than 200 mm on Y axis.
How do I retrieve those 20 mm?
How do I set an Y offset?

Not that I print that much, but it doesn't work with the print bed calibration model. So it tries to travel to `Y209` and fails.

Comment: To me your question is not clear. What do you mean by the 20 mm? There is 30 in the question title. You specified a max of 200, it's clear it won't go further than that.